# How can I peek at values from a thread for time to time?

Tags: java, multithreading, procfs

I'm projecting a monitoring client in Java which will read information from `/proc`. I have a main class `MonitoringClient` and `ProcParser` class. My `ProcParser` extends `Thread`.

I thought it would be a good approach to instantiate many (four: cpu, memory, disk and network) `ProcParser` objects, passing one of the components which I want to measure in the constructor. Then, in the run method I switch between then - and each object will parse one of those. A code would be something like:

```
ProcParser pp_Cpu = new ProcParser(UsageType.CPU, 1000, Pid.getPid());
ProcParser pp_Memory = new ProcParser(UsageType.MEMORY, 1000, Pid.getPid());
ProcParser pp_Disk = new ProcParser(UsageType.DISK, 1000, Pid.getPid());
ProcParser pp_Network = new ProcParser(UsageType.NETWORK, 1000, Pid.getPid());

ArrayList<String> cpuData = null;
ArrayList<String> memoryData = null;
ArrayList<String> diskData = null;
ArrayList<String> networkData = null;

pp_Cpu.start();
pp_Memory.start();
pp_Disk.start();
pp_Network.start();

for (;;) {
    if (pp_Cpu.isReady() && pp_Memory.isReady()
&& pp_Disk.isReady() && pp_Network.isReady()) {

        cpuData = pp_Cpu.getUsageData();
        memoryData = pp_Memory.getUsageData();
        diskData = pp_Disk.getUsageData();
        networkData = pp_Network.getUsageData();
    } else {
        sleep(1000); //this does not work. I have to extend to Thread also the main class?
    }
}
```

How do I peek the gathered values time to time?  Also, is the way I'm creating the threads (one for each main component) a good approach from the Java Threading point of view?  Thanks in advance.

Run method inside the ProcParser.

```
@Override
    public void run() {
        if ((this.usageType == null) || (this.sleepTime < 0) || (this.processPid < 0)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }

        //Forever sleep and gather the usage values
        for (;;) {
            this.ready = false;
            switch (this.usageType) {
                case CPU:
                    this.gatherCpuUsage();
                    this.ready = true;
                    break;
                case MEMORY:
                    this.gatherMemoryUsage(this.processPid);
                    this.ready = true;
                    break;
                case DISK:
                    this.gatherDiskUsage();
                    break;
                case NETWORK:
                    this.gatherNetworkUsage();
                    break;
                case PARTITION:
                    this.gatherPartitionUsage();
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: How long does it take you to run through `/proc`?  Do you really need this thread complexity?

Comment: Are you doing this for fun? Because if you're not you should look at Htop.

Comment: @Stranger_in_the_night: yeap, is for fun, I know HTop, thanks!

Comment: @Gray: is just to exercise some threading in Java, i have a serialized code in c++ and is pretty fast to read /proc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I peek the gathered values time to time?

I am assuming that your `ProcParser` threads run in the background, read in the CPU data  (for example) from `/proc`, and then sleep.  You might want to consider using an [`AtomicReference`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicReference.html).  Something like the following:

```
 private final AtomicReference<List<String>> cpuDataReference =
     new AtomicReference<List<String>>();
 ...

 ProcParser pp_Cpu =
     new ProcParser(UsageType.CPU, 1000, Pid.getPid(), cpuDataReference);
 ...

 // in your `ProcParser`
 List<String> cpuDataList = new ArrayList<String>();
 // read in the /proc files into the list
 ...
 // save it in the AtomicReference passed into the constructor
 dataReference.set(cpuDataList);

 // other threads could then get the latest list
 List<String> cpuDataList = cpuDataReference.get();
```

You might want to `set()` an unmodifiable list if you are worried about the consumers changing the lists.

> Is the way I'm creating the threads (one for each main component) a good approach from the Java Threading point of view?

If this was not an exercise, I'd say that you didn't need the thread complexity -- that it doesn't buy you much.  Choosing which tasks need a thread, how many threads to create, etc.. are critical decisions that need to be made in these cases.

Generically, you should consider making `ProcParser` implement `Runnable` instead of extending `Thread` and then say `new Thread(new ProcParser(...))`.  That's a recommended pattern.  You should also always consider using the `ExecutorService` classes returned by the `Executors` class.  Those thread-pools take over the administration of the threads and make your code much simpler.

Comment: If I understood the AtomicReference<List<String>>, I will pass it to my Thread, and later after the Thread has finished seting it I can get the values from another Thread?

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I still did not get the polling part. I edit my question to add some code. My main Thread will create the four other threads, and periodicaly get the latest list from the AtomicReference. I don't how to control this. I cannot fire wait() from the run method and, now implementing Runnable, cannot do a check in a bool method...=/

Comment: One thing you can do is have a private final Object lock = new Object(); and synchronize and notify on it when you set the atomic reference.  Then in main you can synchronize and then check the atomic reference and wait if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of polling `is_ready`, look into `Object.wait` and `Object.notifyAll`.  You can write a `ProcParser.waitUntilReady` method using `Object.wait` and use `Object.notifyAll` to wake up any threads that are waiting until its ready when the working thread produces a result.

Alternatively, since what your parser is doing is producing a list of items, look into producer consumer queues in `java.util.concurrent`.

Comment: to this, I should move my for(;;) to inside the overrided run, and just surround the thread with try{}catch{InterrupException}?